# Regex that matches integers in between whitespace or start/end of string only

Tags: regex

I'm currently using the pattern: `\b\d+\b`, testing it with these entries:

```
numb3r 
2
3454 
3.214
test
```

I only want it to catch 2, and 3454. It works great for catching number words, except that the boundary flags `(\b)` include `"."` as consideration as a separate word. I tried excluding the period, but had troubles writing the pattern.

Basically I want to remove integer words, and just them alone.

Comment: In which context do you use regex ? grep ? vim ? perl ? other...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use lookaround instead if all you want to match is whitespace:

```
(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: To catch negative numbers you can add [-+]? to catch negative numbers too.  The regex becomes:  (?<=\s|^)[-+]?\d+(?=\s|$)

Comment: overcomplicated

Comment: Linter does not like this

Answer (score 119):

All you want is the below regex:

```
^\d+$
```

Comment: Works until you need to handle integers that are negative.

Comment: This also will match leading zeros. Which i wouldnt expect you would want.

Comment: Leading zeros aren't invalid, are they? They're meaningless, yes, but I'm not sure that they're invalid.

Answer (score 68):

Similar to manojlds but includes the optional negative/positive numbers:

```
var regex = /^[-+]?\d+$/;
```

EDIT

If you don't want to allow zeros in the front (`023` becomes invalid), you could write it this way:

```
var regex = /^[-+]?[1-9]\d*$/;
```

EDIT 2

As @DmitriyLezhnev pointed out, if you want to allow the number `0` to be valid by itself but still invalid when in front of other numbers (example: `0` is valid, but `023` is invalid). Then you could use

```
var regex = /^([+-]?[1-9]\d*|0)$/
```

Comment: Still allows "023", doesn't it?

Comment: I'd improve it liek this:
`var regex = /^([+-]?[1-9]\d*|0)$/`

Comment: DmitriyLezhnev's comment (directly above mine) is the best since it allows just plain 0 as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would add this as a comment to the other good answers, but I need more reputation to do so. Be sure to allow for scientific notation if necessary, i.e. 3e4 = 30000. This is default behavior in many languages. I found the following regex to work:

```
/^[-+]?\d+([Ee][+-]?\d+)?$/;
//          ^^              If 'e' is present to denote exp notation, get it
//             ^^^^^          along with optional sign of exponent
//                  ^^^       and the exponent itself
//        ^            ^^     The entire exponent expression is optional
```

Answer (score 4):

This just allow positive integers.

```
^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution matches integers:

- Negative integers are matched (-1,-2,etc)
- Single zeroes are matched (0)
- Negative zeroes **are not** (-0, -01, -02)
- Empty spaces are not matched ('')

```
/^(0|-*[1-9]+[0-9]*)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^([+-]?[0-9]\d*|0)$
```

will accept numbers with leading "+", leading "-" and leadings "0"

Answer (score 1):

Try `/^(?:-?[1-9]\d*$)|(?:^0)$/`.

It matches positive, negative numbers as well as zeros.

It doesn't match input like `00`, `-0`, `+0`, `-00`, `+00`, `01`.

Online testing available at http://rubular.com/r/FlnXVL6SOq

Comment: I think it should catch `01`.

Comment: @BlackThunder It doesn't. In JS console `/^(?:-?[1-9]\d*$)|(?:^0)$/.test('01')` returns false.

Comment: Maybe he meant 01. In any case it doesn't catch the trailing period as long as there isn't a number proceeding it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case where I needed positive and negative integers that should NOT include zero-starting numbers like 01258 but should of course include 0

```
^(-?[1-9]+\d*)$|^0$
```

Example of valid values:
"3",
"-3",
"0",
"-555",
"945465464654"

Example of not valid values:
"0.0",
"1.0",
"0.7",
"690.7",
"0.0001",
"a",
"",
" ",
".",
"-",
"001",
"00.2",
"000.5",
".3",
"3.",
" -1",
"+100",
"--1",
"-.1",
"-0",
"00099",
"099"

Answer (score 0):

^(-+)?[1-9][0-9]*$
starts with a - or + for 0 or 1 times, then you want a non zero number (because there is not such a thing -0 or +0) and then it continues with any number from 0 to 9