# How to write Regex for input values?

Tags: javascript, regex

What RegEx can I use to parse a string so that it accepts only integers and the `/` character?

Comment: You should have tried something before asking a *quick reply*.

Comment: What have you tried already? StackOverflow is here to help you, not write your code for you.

Comment: A previous post partially solves your problem hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043551/regex-match-integer-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = '123/4';
var b = 'e123/4';
```

Variant 1

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[0-9/]+$');

console.log((a.match(regex)) ? true : false); // true
console.log((b.match(regex)) ? true : false); // false
```

Variant 2

```
var regex = /^[0-9/]+$/;

console.log((a.match(regex)) ? true : false); // true
console.log((b.match(regex)) ? true : false); // false
```

Variant 3

```
var regex = /^[\d\/]+$/;

console.log((a.match(regex)) ? true : false); // true
console.log((b.match(regex)) ? true : false); // false
```

Comment: why not `var regex = /^[0-9/]+$/;`?

Comment: I'm just used to write it that way. Shouldn't be a difference though, right?

Comment: Btw, you could also write the regex as `/^[\d\/]+$/`.

Comment: I think using the constructor should be slightly less efficient, because you need to create a string object and have the overhead of another function call. Plus, the syntax gets a lot more ugly, when you use escapes (because you need to double all backslashes). I'd only use the constructor for dynamically created (concatenated) patterns.